# Cannot read data in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a login page using the Firebase realtime database and JavaScript/HTML. I've already created a sign up page where after one signs up, they are given a unique ID. This ID is the title of the parent of all the user's data in the firebase database. The login page has a form where one pastes this ID, and then is able to access the data they've inputted when signing up. My problem is that the code is not retrieving any of the data (specifically once the user logs in, I want their email to be alerted, but this is not occurring). Can anyone help me with this? My code and an image of my database is below:

**JavaScript:**

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "..................",
  authDomain: "..................",
  databaseURL: "..................",
  projectId: "..................",
  storageBucket: "..................",
  messagingSenderId: "..................",
  appId: "..................",
  measurementId: ".................."
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Reference messages collection


document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', getData);

function getData(){
    var loginId = document.getElementById("loginId").value;

    firebase.database().ref('user/' + loginId).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        var address = snapshot.val().address; 
        var city = snapshot.val().city;
        var email = snapshot.val().email;
        var firstname = snapshot.val().firstname;
        var lastname = snapshot.val().lastname;
        var password = snapshot.val().password;
        var phonenumber = snapshot.val().phonenumber;
        var postalcode = snapshot.val().postalcode;
        var state = snapshot.val().state;

        alert(email);
        
    });

}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Web Building</title>
  <!--<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">>-->
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" />-->
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">>-->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="brand"><span>Web</span> Building</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="company-info">
         <h3>Web Building</h3>
         <ul>
           <li><i class="fa fa-road"></i> 1 Something st</li>
           <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (555) 555-5555</li>
           <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> test@test.test</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="contact">
         <h3>Login</h3>

         <form id="loginForm">
           <p>
             <label>Paste Login ID</label>
             <input type="text" name="loginId" id="loginId">
           </p>
           <p class="full">
             <button type="submit">Login</button>
           </p>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
   <script src="login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Firebase Database:**
[image: screenshot of the firebase database]

**EDIT**

Here is the structure of my database:

```
{
  "user" : {
    "8gfpBhVrIi" : {
      "address" : "3 second street",
      "city" : "albuquerque",
      "email" : "tedbert999@gmail.com",
      "firstname" : "Teddy",
      "lastname" : "Porfiris",
      "password" : "password",
      "phonenumber" : "4161231234",
      "postalcode" : "123456",
      "state" : "New Mexico"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code to receive the login Id once one has signed up:

**JavaScript:**

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "..................",
  authDomain: "..................",
  databaseURL: "..................",
  projectId: "..................",
  storageBucket: "..................",
  messagingSenderId: "..................",
  appId: "..................",
  measurementId: ".................."
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


// Listen for form submit
document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

// Generate Id

function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}



// Submit form
function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get values
  var firstname = getInputVal('firstname');
  var lastname = getInputVal('lastname');
  var state = getInputVal('state');
  var email = getInputVal('email');
  var phonenumber = getInputVal('phonenumber');
  var password = getInputVal('password');
  var address = getInputVal('address');
  var city = getInputVal('city');
  var postalcode = getInputVal('postalcode');

  var accountId = makeid(10)
  // Save message
  saveMessage(firstname, lastname, state, email, phonenumber, password, address, city, postalcode, accountId);
  var id_sentence = document.getElementById('loginId');
  var accountId_text = document.createTextNode(accountId);
  id_sentence.appendChild(accountId_text);

  // Show alert
  document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';

  // Hide alert after 3 seconds
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';
  },3000);

  // Clear form
  document.getElementById('contactForm').reset();
}

// Function to get get form values
function getInputVal(id){
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

// Save message to firebase
function saveMessage(firstname, lastname, state, email, phonenumber, password, address, city, postalcode, userId){
  // Reference messages collection

  var newMessageRef = firebase.database().ref('/user/' + userId);
  newMessageRef.set({
    firstname:firstname,
    lastname:lastname,
    state:state,
    email:email,
    phonenumber:phonenumber,
    password:password,
    address:address,
    city:city,
    postalcode:postalcode
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Web Design</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="brand"><span>Good</span> Web Design</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="company-info">
        <h3>Web Design</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-road"></i> 11 street st</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (555) 555-5555</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> test@tes.test</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        <div class="alert">Your have been signd up!</div>
        <form id="contactForm">
          <p>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Last Name" id="lastname">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>State</label>
            <select name="state" id="state">
              <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
              <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
              <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
              <option value="California">California</option>
              <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
              <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
              <option value="D.C.">D.C.</option>
              <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
              <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
              <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
              <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
              <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
              <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
              <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
              <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
              <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
              <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
              <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
              <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
              <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
              <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
              <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
              <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
              <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
              <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
              <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
              <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota </option>
              <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
              <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
              <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
              <option value="New York">New York</option>
              <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
              <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
              <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
              <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
              <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
              <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
              <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
              <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
              <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
              <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
              <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
              <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
              <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
              <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
              <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
              <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
              <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
              <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Postal Code</label>
            <input type="text" name="postalcode" id="postalcode">
          </p>
          <p class="full">
            <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
          </p><br>

        </form>

      <div id="loginId">Your Login ID is: </div>


        <form action="/login.html">
            <p class="login">
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the image of the error I am getting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following code and let me know if it works:

I think a '/' is needed to access the Firebase as we can see in the [Firebase Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) and also you need to use backticks (`), and not single quotes ('), to wrap a string as follows:

```
function getData(){
   var loginId = document.getElementById("loginId").value;
   firebase.database().ref(`/user/` + loginId).once('value').then(function 
   (snapshot) {
        ...
        ...
    }).catch(function(){
        console.log('error');
   });
}
```

```
function saveMessage(firstname, lastname, state, email, phonenumber, password, address, city, postalcode, userId){
  // Reference messages collection

  var newMessageRef = firebase.database().ref(`/user/` + userId);
  newMessageRef.set({
    firstname:firstname,
    lastname:lastname,
    state:state,
    email:email,
    phonenumber:phonenumber,
    password:password,
    address:address,
    city:city,
    postalcode:postalcode
   });
}
```

Comment: I have made the added the information you have asked for in the post. Adding the slashes didn't work.

Comment: I am looking at your edit post, in the meantime could you please provide the output of loginId variable?

Comment: Each output is a random 10 digit string of numbers @Nibrass H. This string is generated every time one signs up using the added code above. This string also acts as the title of the of the header that contains the new user's account details in the firebase database. Is this the information you need? If not please comment and I will send whatever you need right away :)

Comment: Could you please print the value of snaphot in getData function? Is that null? What does the variables address, city, email returns? Please console.log(snaphot), console.log(address) and share the output with me?

Comment: Also please add a catch block to handle the error in case it's giving an error. You can use following : firebase.database().ref('user/' + loginId).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        ....
    }).catch(function() {
    console.log('error');
});

Comment: I do not recieve any output when I perform console.log('snapshot') or console.log('address') @Nibrass H. Also when I perform the code you have given me I do not get any result (in the comment below I have pasted my updated code with the code you gave me just in case I implemented your code wrong). I am however getting an error when I run both the console.logs and the other code you gave me. The error can be seen as an image in the post.

Comment: function getData(){
 firebase.database().ref('user/' + loginId).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
  var address = snapshot.val().address; 
  var city = snapshot.val().city;
  var email = snapshot.val().email;
  var firstname = snapshot.val().firstname;
  var lastname = snapshot.val().lastname;
  var password = snapshot.val().password;
  var phonenumber = snapshot.val().phonenumber;
  var postalcode = snapshot.val().postalcode;
  var state = snapshot.val().state;

  console.log(snapshot)
  console.log(address);

 }).catch(function() { console.log('error'); });

}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221178/discussion-between-nibrass-h-and-teddy-porfiris).

Comment: Please look at the comments I left in the chat. You can access it with the previous link.